Why the second layer is not working with GetKeyState?
My AHK script has the following part:
#If GetKeyState("RAlt", "P")  ; When Right Alt is pressed
    i::Up
    j::Left
    k::Down
    l::Right
#If  ; Ends the block

However, whenever I hold the right Alt and press any of those scoped keys, nothing happens. As you may have noticed, I’ve only just started using AHK and would like to get a practical insight into this issue, for now.
To just have sure I don't have any conflicting code, here is my full (simple) script:
; Colemak Mod-DH mapping for ANSI boards


;SC010::q
;SC011::w
SC012::f
SC013::p
SC014::b
SC015::j
SC016::l
SC017::u
SC018::y


;SC01E::a
SC01F::r
SC020::s
SC021::t
;SC022::g
SC023::m
SC024::n
SC025::e
SC026::i
SC027::o

SC02c::x
SC02d::c
SC02e::d
;SC02f::v
SC030::z
SC031::k
SC032::h

#If GetKeyState("RAlt", "P")  ; When Right Alt is pressed
    i::Up
    j::Left
    k::Down
    l::Right
#If  ; Ends the block


